# Obtaining rsh on Windows 7 Professional

Tags: windows-7

How can one install the `rsh` in Windows 7 Professional?

Comment: Have you tried Cygwin?

Comment: `rsh` is contained within `Subsystem for Unix-based Applications (SUA)` just install that component provided you have a supported version of Windows 7.  Otherwise you will have to install ported version of a GNU unix utility.  Just take your pick.

Comment: I may be wrong here but isn't `rsh` insecure and obsolete?

Comment: @Gael - I am sure it is hence the reason its no longer included by default.

Comment: The degree of security and obsoleteness has to be understood in context. It would be more correct to say that rsh does not *implement* any security, which makes it obsolete in scenarios where no other service is in the way between an RSH service host and a potentially malicious (by virtue or ignorance) entity. When you have a closed network where you just need to access host shells, it can be neither meaningfully called "insecure" nor "obsolete". Paranoia has not been proven to bring about more security, it is understanding security that has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft includes `rsh` in a UNIX utilities add-on [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2391). Unfortunately, it only officially supports Windows 7 Enterprise and Windows 7 Ultimate.

A Google search pointed me here: http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/bchafy/rsh_vista.html. If you just need `rsh`, this is probably what you want.

If you would like to use `rsh` in a UNIX-like environment, or also need the RSH server `rshd`, try [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com).

Comment: If you want to try Cygwin, just ditch RSH and use SSH instead.